# Devops - Linked ARM template - Geneate blob storage SAS toekn using powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to deploy linked ARM template using devops.

Instead of hard coding SAS token, I would like to generate SAS token using powershell script but I'm not familiar with using powershell to generate blob SAS token.

Any help with this powershell will be appreciated!

Comment: @Saz Not get your latest information, is the below workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated 0512:**

If you want to get the account key automatically, you should take use this cmdlet [Get-AzStorageAccountKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccountkey?view=azps-3.8.0).

The example:

1.Get both of the key1 and key2 of your storage account:

```
 Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "your_resourceGroupName" -Name "your_storageAccountName"
```

Test result:

[image]

2.Get the key1 of your storage account:

```
$s=Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "your_resourceGroupName" -Name "your_storageAccountName"

$s[0].Value
```

Test result:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

If you're using azure powershell az module, then you can use [New-AzStorageBlobSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageblobsastoken?view=azps-3.8.0) cmdlet.

Sample code:

```
$accountName="xxx"
$accountKey="xxxx"

$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Container "ContainerName" -Blob "BlobName" -Permission rwd -Context $context
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I've small issue using above script since I don't know my account key since I'm deploying my storage account via ARM template and entire solution is automated.

Is there any way to get account key through powershell script instead of hard coding it.